# Printing mySQL table to webpage

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to php and I want to use it to print out the contents of my mySQL table to a web page. So far I have the 'connect to database' part, but I'm really stuck as to how to actually print out the data, preferably in a HTML table.

My PHP:

```
<?php    

$username="root";
$password="password";
$database="posts";
mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query= "SELECT * FROM input";

$result=mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();

?>
```

My HTML for my web page:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/viewstyle.css">
  <title>Database View</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Database View Page </h1>
    <p> Here you can view the Database </p>
    <script src="display.php"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your time.

EDITED:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/viewstyle.css">
  <title>Database View</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Database View Page </h1>
    <p> Here you can view the Database </p>


    <?php

        $username="root";
        $password="password";
        $database="posts";
        mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
        mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

        $query= "SELECT * FROM input";

        $result=mysql_query($query);

        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Age</th></tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
          echo '<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $row['surname'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $row['age'] . '</td>';
          echo "</tr>"; 
          }
         echo "</table>";

                     mysql_close();

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When my page loads it now shows:

" "; echo " Sample Sample Description"; while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo '' . $row['firstname'] . ''; echo '' . $row['surname'] . ''; echo '' . $row['age'] . ''; echo ""; } echo ""; ?> mysql_close(); "

As text on my webpage.

Comment: given you're loading your fetch-from-db PHP via a `<script>` block, your PHP code **HAS** to output valid javascript code... Unless your data is going to be dynamically changed, there is NO point in loading the data that way - the "html" page should be a php script and output the table's contents at page generation time, saving your a full http request which the `<script>` would trigger.

Comment: So you are saying instead of loading the script from a seperate file, i should simply have the PHP embedded in the HTML between <script> tags? @Marc B

Comment: pretty much. there's usually very little point in having php output javascript so you can build html on the client side - it's generally far more efficient to have php build the html directly.

Comment: Have I misinterpreted your question? @dat_guy I posted an answer below. If that's not what you're looking for, I can delete it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, I dont think you misunderstood, I have to leave the house for a few mins so i havent had a chance to try it yet

Comment: Not a problem @dat_guy I'll be here if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a loop, I'm using a `while` loop in this example.

Depending on the column you wish to show:

Modify `$row['column']` (column being the name of the column itself)

```
<?php
$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="xxx";
mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query= "SELECT * FROM input";

$result=mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo '<p>'.$row['column'].' </p>';
    }

mysql_close();

?>
```

If you want to show it in an HTML table, you would use something to the effect of:

```
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>Sample</th> <th>Sample Description</th></tr>";

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo '<td>' . $row['column_1'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['column_2'] . '</td>';
  echo "</tr>"; 
  }
 echo "</table>";
```

If you have more columns you wish to show, simply add another one:

```
echo '<td>' . $row['column_1'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['column_2'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['column_3'] . '</td>';
```

and so on...

and adding a 3rd header for the top cells:

```
echo "<tr><th>Row 1</th><th>Row 2</th><th>Row 3</th></tr>";
```

If you wish to add more cell headers, just add more `<th>Row X</th>` before `</tr>`

---

Sidenote:

As Marc B [pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817688/printing-mysql-table-to-webpage#comment34799699_22817688), you may want to use an `href` instead of `<script src="display.php"></script>` depending on what's inside that file which isn't posted in your question.

For example:

```
<a href="display.php">View database</a>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: Do i need to define $row? Also, if i use the info that you have given me in this question and use href to use my script, will that work without me having to change anything? Or would it be better to use it directly in my HTML?

Comment: Yes, you need to define `$row`. Is there a particular reason as to why you don't want to do that? @dat_guy

Comment: I was just wondering did you forget to define it in your answer?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It's in there in `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` and `echo '<p>'.$row['column'].' </p>';` etc. Did you try it and you're having problems? @dat_guy

Comment: Ah right, sorry. I misinterpreted the assignment as equality. I have tried it and my page is showing up blank (apart from my header) I will edit my question to show how my code now looks.

Comment: Don't forget to change the word `column` in `$row['column']` for the column name in your table you wish to show. @dat_guy You may also need to pass DB connection to your query.

Comment: I saw your edit. Remove the `<script>` and `</script>` from your code @dat_guy

Comment: Also, place `mysql_close();` after `echo "</table>";` @dat_guy You're closing your DB connection prematurely.

Comment: I tested your code with my DB/table stuff and it all checks out. Are you running this from your own computer or on a hosted site? @dat_guy Plus, is your file extension set to `.php` or `.html`? If it's set to `.html`, change it to `.php` that's why you're getting that showing up as code.

Comment: At the moment all of the code(in my edit using your answer) is in a file called 'view.html'. So are you saying i should change that to 'view.php' ? Also if i do that, would i still be able to use my <head> tags etc to store metadata? Or would i simply do that in the php script by doing 'echo <head>' etc ? @Fred-ii-

Comment: Yes, it must be `.php` - Plus you can use `<head>` etc. just as long as it's not mixed into your PHP. The way you have it now is OK, just change your file extension to `.php` and it will work. @dat_guy

Comment: I also edited your (edited) code. From `echo "<tr> <th>Sample</th> <th>Sample Description</th></tr>";` to `echo "<tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Age</th></tr>";` so that it will show the right headers on top. @dat_guy

Comment: Thank you, I have changed my file to .php and made it exec on my server, although now Im having a separate problem, when I load the file in my browser, it tries to download the file. Im guessing that may be something wrong on my server config? @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome. Yes it's a server config issue, however I don't run my own server and have always been on hosted sites. I'd like to help you out with that, but I know next to nothing about setting up PHP on a localhost. I do know enough to say that that is the issue, but not enough to help out in the area. @dat_guy

Comment: Added note: If you have access to a hosted site, try it out on there. @dat_guy

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the MySQL result you need to read rows from it.

Check out the sample code on [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) (Example #2 Procedural style)

Also: `mysql` is deprecated, use `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mysqli_fetch_array()` It is easier than your using method.